# serilog intercept logs and modify log

Tags: logging, serilog

I want to intercept the logs which are about to be written by serilog and modify it based upon some logic, i.e, look for some sensitive information in the logs and mask it.

The closest I have reached till the point is to find ILogEventEnricher

```
public class LogEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
       //do something here, but what?
    }
}
```

but the property MessagTemplate of LogEvent is readonly.
Any Idea how can I intercept the logs and modify them before logging.

Comment: Make a Sink, add WriteTo.Sink into the config and mutate there with the ILogEvent properties mutation functionss  (but please don't go down a rabbit hole of fixing stuff when it's too late - such mutations need to happen at source)

Comment: Already using serilog.console.sinks and writing on the file system and console, I do not want to add a custom sink, but would like to only modify what's being written on to the file and console.

Comment: Fair point (I _think_ you're right an enricher has the same facilities in terms of mutating (which, I repeat, you should seek to avoid!)) - have a read of the source of serilog/serilog - there' a good chance the template can't be touched, but the `logEvent` should allow you to arr/remove/change properties, no ?

Comment: https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-timewarp/blob/master/Serilog.Sinks.TimeWarp/Program.cs does a similar thing to what you're after (check out the `Main()` method to see it all wired up) - short on time to write this up as an answer now, though, sorry. HTH!

Answer (score 2):

A common way to deal with that with Serilog, is to tell Serilog not to log certain properties when destructuring objects.

For example, via [`Destructurama.Attributed`](https://github.com/destructurama/attributed):

```
public class LoginCommand
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [NotLogged]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

You can read more in this blogpost: **[Using attributes to control destructuring in Serilog](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/07/using-attributes-to-control-destructuring-in-serilog/)**.

---

You can also do something similar via [`Destructurama.ByIgnoring`](https://github.com/destructurama/by-ignoring)

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByIgnoringProperties<User>(u => u.Password)
    // Other logger configuration
    .CreateLogger()
```

Comment: This would have been a perfect solution if I was logging objects, but this is not the case for me. 
I am logging a payload before sending it to the message bus, since this payload is a string, using attributes are ruled out, the only way for me is to intercept this payload before logging and modify it if it contains sensitive information
Another scenario is where all HTTP requests are being used. for some reason, some sensitive information is being passed as a query string(bad design) and OAuth token, this sensitive info from HTTP requests and oAuth token are also not good logging candidates